# 2 оператора присваивания или один?

Tags: c++, c++11, оператор-присваивания

Итак имеется два оператора присваивания - копирующий и перемещающий, например такие:

```
Implementation& operator= (const Implementation &  other) noexcept;
Implementation& operator= (      Implementation && other) noexcept;
```

При этом в данном [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) (в первом ответе) говорится, что есть определенные преимущества объявления оператора `=` следующим образом, т.е. по значению:

```
Implementation& operator= (      Implementation    other) noexcept;
```

Т.е. в таком случае мы можем не объявлять оператор, принимающий `&&`? Иначе просто возникнет неопределенность. Почему же тогда в стандартной библиотеке используется первая техника, а в бусте можно найти такое:

```
#ifdef BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
        template < typename ValueType >
        any& operator= (const ValueType& rhs)
        {
            any(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        any& operator= (any rhs)
        {
            any(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }
#else 
        any& operator= (const any& rhs)
        {
            any(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        any& operator= (any&& rhs) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
        {
            rhs.swap(*this);
            any().swap(rhs);
            return *this;
        }
#endif
```

Почему не сделать во втором блоке препроцессора ту же реализацию:

```
        any& operator= (any rhs)
        {
            any(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }
```

Или это сделано для того, чтобы в операторе `=`, принимающем `&&` сделать обнуление `rvalue` значения?

Comment: Ответ по ссылке и блок кода из буста предельно ясны, по моему. Эта «техника» использовалась для кода, что был до C++11. В C++11 для перемещения есть специальная конструкция, поэтому ответ по ссылке для C++11 не подходит.

Comment: Что-то я не врублюсь, почему вообще при `operator= (any rhs)` нужно делать копию `any(rhs).swap(*this);` - почему не `rhs.swap(*this);` сразу? Все равно при передаче по значению копия *уже* сделана...

Comment: Кстати, гуру в стандарте - скажите, а при перемещении обязательно занулять объект? Мне казалось, что он может находиться в любом, лишь бы корректном, состоянии после перемещения, нет? Т.е. насколько необходим вот этот вызов - `any().swap(rhs);`?

Comment: @Harry, стандарт не налагает ограничений на состояние объекта после перемещения данных из оного. Насколько необходим этот вызов, нужно узнавать у разработчиков этой библиотеки, либо же попытаться понять самостоятельно.

Comment: @Harry да в бусте такое встречается. Плюс я взял код из (судя по всему) довольно старой версии.

Comment: @ixSci Спасибо, мне тоже так казалось :)

Comment: @Harry Похоже на копипасту.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Почему не сделать во втором блоке препроцессора ту же реализацию:

```
   any& operator= (any rhs)
   {
       any(rhs).swap(*this);
       return *this;
   }
```

Дело в том, что с приходом C++11 и появлением семантики перемещения появилась возможность разделить ситуации, когда нам действительно нужна новая копия объекта и ситуации, когда мы хотим только переместить один объект в другой. При таком разделении копирующий оператор присваивания (или конструктор) может бросать исключения, а перемещающий оператор практически всегда можно реализовать без бросания исключений и без необходимости создавать временные объекты. Соответственно с переходом на С++11 приведенный конструктор получится неоптимальным так как 1) он может кидать исключения 2) он всегда создает временный объект.

Пример сценария с оверхедом:

```
any first{};
any second{};
first = ::std::move(second); // создаем еще и третий объект - аргумент оператора
```

Использовать copy-and-swap оператор присваивания совместно с перемещающим оператором присваивания не получится, так как в этом случае при присваивании rvalue reference компилятор не сможет выбрать между ними.

Comment: + его не получится использовать в стандартных контейнерах оптимально (т.е. с перемещением), всегда будет копирование.